# Lerna avoid symlink

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lerna, monorepo

I'm using the below command

```
lerna bootstrap --hoist
```

I want lerna to install all dev and prod dependencies of the packages to the main root node_modules.
**Some packages are dependencies of each other.**

When I run the bootstrap command it installs all the dependencies to the root node_modules.
But after that process it symlink some of the packages to each other.

I just want the install all dependencies to the root node_modules including dependent packages.I don't want any symlink dependency.

How can I avoid symlink process ?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this problem? Looking for a way to avoid symlinks as well haha.